# Will my Green's function approximation be any good?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, approximations, greens-functions

I would like to use the Greens Function $G(t,t')$, satisfying \begin{equation} \int G^{-1}(t,s)G(s,t') ds = \left( \begin{array}{cc} \delta(t-t') & 0 \\ 0 & \delta(t-t') \end{array} \right) \end{equation}

where $$ G^{-1}(t,t') =
\begin{pmatrix}
-(3+\frac{d}{dt})\delta(t-t') & - 2 \pi t 
 \delta(t-t') \\
2 \pi t \delta(t-t') & -(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{d}{dt}) \delta(t-t') \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

---

(detail added in response to a comment)

I can't find a closed form expression for $G$, but if I approximate $G^{-1} \approx H$ (changing only the upper left component) there is a closed form approximate expression for $G$, as follows:

Choosing
$$ H(t,t') =
\begin{pmatrix}
-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{d}{dt})\delta(t-t') & - 2 \pi t \delta(t-t')\\
2 \pi t \delta(t-t') & -(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{d}{dt}) \delta(t-t')\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We then require
\begin{equation} \int H(t,s)G(s,t') ds = \left( \begin{array}{cc} \delta(t-t') & 0 \\ 0 & \delta(t-t') \end{array} \right) \end{equation}
Columns of $G = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{smallmatrix} \right) = \Theta \left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ (where $\Theta$ is a step function) may be solved for separately.

$A$ and $C$ must jointly satisfy (the 0,0) identity, integrating out the $s$ variable leaves:
\begin{equation}
-\Big( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{d}{dt}\Big) A - 2 \pi t C = \delta
\end{equation}
$$\implies$$
\begin{equation} \left(-\frac{1}{2} a - a' - 2\pi t c\right)\Theta = (1+a)\delta\end{equation}
and the (0,1) identity which amounts to:
\begin{equation} \left(-\frac{1}{2} c - c' - 2\pi t a \right)\Theta = c\delta\end{equation}

I find $A$ and $B$ to be
\begin{equation}
A = \Theta (t-s) \left(-e^{\frac{s-t}{2 }}\right) \cos (\pi  (s-t) (s+t))
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
C = \Theta (t-s) e^{\frac{s-t}{2}} \sin (\pi  (s-t) (s+t))
\end{equation}

Plugging these in, and noticing that some of the terms proportional to $\delta$ will be identically zero, shows they should work as solutions.

I then use the same argument for $B$ and $D$.

---

Assuming the above solution for $G$ works, **is there any way to know how good an approximate $G$, derived from $H$, would be? And if this approximation idea is no good, how can I deal with finding a useable $G$?**

Comment: Huh? your antisymmetric trial *H* fails to yield a diagonal r.h.s., let alone an identity. Why don't you take an ansatz *((a,b),(-b,c))* and solve for the operators  *a,b,c* ?

Comment: Hi, I have added additional information in my question showing how I arrived at a solution using $H$. Hopefully I have not made a mistake anywhere!

Answer (score 2):

You've made it hard to see by gratuitously complicating and misframing the problem. Your first duty is to integrate out the useless dummy variable, given your effective Ansatz for $G(s-t') = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} A(t') & B(t') \\ C((t') & D(t') \end{smallmatrix} \right) \delta(s-t')$,
$$\int\!\!ds~~ H(t,s)G(s,t') \\ = \int\!\!ds~~\begin{pmatrix}
-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{d}{dt})  & - 2 \pi t  \\
2 \pi t  & -(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{d}{dt})  
\end{pmatrix}\delta (t-s) 
\begin{pmatrix}
A(t') &  B(t')\\
 C(t') &  D(t') 
\end{pmatrix}\delta(s-t') \\
=\begin{pmatrix}
-( 1/2+\tfrac{d}{dt})  & - 2 \pi t  \\
2 \pi t  & -( 1/2+\tfrac{d}{dt})  
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
A(t) &  B(t)\\
 C(t) &  D(t) 
\end{pmatrix}\delta(t-t').
 $$

You now need to solve the four operator equations in [Heaviside operator calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_calculus) (e.g. $\partial C =[\partial,C]+C\partial$) for the four operators, *A,B,C,D*,
$$
-( 1/2+\tfrac{d}{dt})A   - 2 \pi t C=1,\\
-( 1/2+\tfrac{d}{dt})C   + 2 \pi t A=0,\\
-( 1/2+\tfrac{d}{dt})B   - 2 \pi t D=0,\\
-( 1/2+\tfrac{d}{dt})D   + 2 \pi t B=1 .
$$
Using the two middle ones you collapse to two equations for two variables, *B,C*, whose symmetry you should note, so one equation.